# Query on Ruby module

Tags: ruby

I was going through some tutorials, where I come with the following code

```
module DecimalCode
  RED = "rgb(255,0,0)"
  GREEN = "rgb(0,128,0)"

  def code
    return "RED : Decimal code #{RED}"
  end


  def DecimalCode.code
    return "GREEN : Decimal code #{GREEN}"
  end

  def hello
    return "Hello world!"
  end

end

include DecimalCode
puts DecimalCode.hello
puts DecimalCode.code
```

My queries,

1. What is the difference between the methods `code` and `DecimalCode.code`
2. When I do not include the module and type `puts DecimalCode.code` it always prints `Green: Decimal code`, why is that so?

Comment: _Sidenote:_ I strongly encourage you to find some other tutorial. The author who suggests using `return` statements in Ruby is barely worth reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The methods in a module may be instance methods or module methods. Instance methods appear as methods in a class when the module is included, module methods do not.

Here, `code` is called instance method in module, whereas `DecimalCode.code` is called module method.